# Layout breaks on react-transition-group animation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactcsstransitiongroup

I am trying to get familiar with `react-transition-group` but having some issues. In a simple component that displays current counter and animates the displayed value on `increment` or `decrement` when a new value enter, it shifts the previous one which creates abrupt effect. It probably happens because a new element with opacity `0` enters the dome and both values are displayed at the same time.

The whole component looks like this:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { TransitionGroup, CSSTransition } from "react-transition-group";

import "./App.css";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    progress: 0
  };
  incr = () => {
    this.setState({
      progress: this.state.progress + 1
    });
  };
  decr = () => {
    this.setState({
      progress: this.state.progress - 1
    });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <TransitionGroup>
          <CSSTransition
            in={true}
            appear={true}
            key={this.state.progress}
            timeout={2000}
            classNames="slide"
          >
            <div key={this.state.progress}>{this.state.progress}</div>
          </CSSTransition>
        </TransitionGroup>
        <button onClick={this.decr}>decr</button>
        <button onClick={this.incr}>incr</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Transition classes look like this:

```
/* slide enter */
.slide-enter {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(0.97) translateX(5px);
  z-index: 1;
}
.slide-enter.slide-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1) translateX(0);
  transition: opacity 3000ms linear 1000ms, transform 3000ms ease-in-out 1000ms;
}

/* slide exit */
.slide-exit {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1) translateX(0);
}
.slide-exit.slide-exit-active {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(0.97) translateX(5px);
  transition: opacity 1500ms linear, transform 1500ms ease-out;
}
.slide-exit-done {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

I want to achieve the following behavior: on increment/decrement current displayed counter fades away, and new one fades in after the current one is not already there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It probably happens because a new element with opacity 0 enters the dome and both values are displayed at the same time.

Yes, that's exactly it. You can use `position: absolute` to remove the elements from the document's flow, and you may also need to somehow compensate for the fact that those elements are removed from the document's flow.

```
<TransitionGroup>
  <CSSTransition
    in={true}
    appear={true}
    key={this.state.progress}
    timeout={2000}
    classNames="slide"
  >
    <div className="animating" key={this.state.progress}>
      {this.state.progress}
    </div>
  </CSSTransition>
</TransitionGroup>
```

CSS

```
.animating {
  position: absolute;
}

button:first-of-type {
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

## Without React Transition Group

JS

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    progress: 0,
    transition: "entering" /* entering | exiting */
  };
  instanceVariables = {
    temporaryProgress: 0,
    timeoutId: null
  };
  animate = () => {
    clearTimeout(this.instanceVariables.timeoutId);
    this.instanceVariables.timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({
        progress: this.instanceVariables.temporaryProgress,
        transition: "entering"
      });
    }, 1000);
    this.setState({
      transition: "exiting"
    });
  };
  incr = () => {
    this.instanceVariables.temporaryProgress += 1;
    this.animate();
  };
  decr = () => {
    this.instanceVariables.temporaryProgress -= 1;
    this.animate();
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className={`animate ${this.state.transition}`}>
          {this.state.progress}
        </div>
        <button onClick={this.decr}>decr</button>
        <button onClick={this.incr}>incr</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

CSS

```
.animate {
  transition: opacity 1s linear, transform 1s ease-in-out;
}

.animate.exiting {
  transform: translateX(20px);
  opacity: 0;
}

.animate.entering {
  transform: translateX(0);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But is there potentially a way to delay exit animation, so it exits before a new one is going to enter? In more complex Layouts  I think giving `absolute` to an element can break lots of things. Thanks!

Comment: `position: absolute` is exactly what I do for [my app shell layout](https://persianturtle.github.io/reason-app-shell-starter-kit/build/) (which uses React Transition Group for route transitions). If you only want one element to appear at a time, then perhaps it's best to not use React Transition Group at all since you don't really need it. You can use normal React for that.

Comment: How would I achieve that, if I just want to set opacity of exiting element to 0 from 1, and vice versa for entering element? I am now battling with layout, to make the element I want to transition absolute, but it does not work so far, so any suggestions on how I can do that without transition group are highly welcome! Thanks again, it means a lot

Comment: @DimitryIvashchuk Sure, I've updated my answer to include an example.

Comment: thanks for your help and advice, I will try to make it work based on them!